# How to get the commit hash that added a line to a file, which is already deleted by the current commit in github repository

Tags: git, github, git-blame

From the pull request found in [here](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/commit/d53489b5b2ad907d01957eb50ddf12dc3611d127) we can see that in the file

> /java/org/wso2/carbon/analytics/apim/internal/TemplateManagerInitializerComponent.java

38,39 and 40 lines have been deleted. Now I need to identify the commit hash (hashes) which added those lines (deleted 38,39 and 40 lines) to the file, but the blame view for the file shown in [here](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/blame/d53489b5b2ad907d01957eb50ddf12dc3611d127/components/org.wso2.analytics.apim/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/analytics/apim/internal/TemplateManagerInitializerComponent.java) does not show the history for the deleted lines . How to get this information from github.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try `git log -S <string>` :

```
git log -S "import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException"
```

---

quoting the doc (`git help log`) about `-S` and its cousin `-G` :

> `-S<string>`
>     Look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the specified string (i.e. addition/deletion) in a file.
>     Intended for the scripter’s use.
>
> It is useful when you’re looking for an exact block of code (like a struct), and want to know the history of that block since
>     it first came into being: use the feature iteratively to feed the interesting block in the preimage back into -S, and keep
>     going until you get the very first version of the block.
>
> `-G<regex>`
>     Look for differences whose patch text contains added/removed lines that match `<regex>`.
>
> To illustrate the difference between `-S<regex> --pickaxe-regex` and `-G<regex>`, consider a commit with the following diff in the
>     same file:
>
> ```
> +    return !regexec(regexp, two->ptr, 1, &regmatch, 0);
>      ...
> -    hit = !regexec(regexp, mf2.ptr, 1, &regmatch, 0);
> ```
>
> While `git log -G"regexec\(regexp"` will show this commit,
>     `git log -S"regexec\(regexp" --pickaxe-regex` will not (because the
>     number of occurrences of that string did not change).
>
> *See the pickaxe entry in gitdiffcore(7) for more information.*